# Why didn't students go to other schools after Dumbledore's death?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, albus-dumbledore, death-eaters

After the death eaters take over the school after Dumbledore's death, I understand it became mandatory for all students to attend school but my question is why didn't students go to other wizarding schools, like Beauxbatons, Durmstrang, or Koldovstoretz?

Comment: Koldovstoretz??

Comment: @randal'thor - [Koldovstoretz](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Koldovstoretz)

Comment: @Richard Hm. Either it should be Koldovstvoretz or the transliteration is wrong on that Wikia page.

Comment: @randal'thor: The article you were just linked to does explain that it's a misspelling.

Comment: Is it just me or does it sound like wordplay on 'cold storage' in reference to its weather? There have been more blatant examples like Ms.Galore from James Bond.

Comment: @aitchnyu - no it's a tranliteration from the word "wizardry" in Russian (koldovstvo).

Answer (score 35):

The quote from the novel is that they're obliged to attend Hogwarts, and Hogwarts alone:

> ‘Ron, as we’re on the run with Harry Potter, the most wanted person in
>   the country, I don’t think it matters. If I was going back to school,
>   it would be different. **What’s Voldemort planning for Hogwarts?’ she
>   asked Lupin.**
>
> **‘Attendance is now compulsory for every young witch and wizard,’ he
>   replied. ‘That was announced yesterday. It’s a change, because it was
>   never obligatory before.** Of course, nearly every witch and wizard in
>   Britain has been educated at Hogwarts, but **their parents had the right
>   to teach them at home or send them abroad if they preferred**. This way,
>   Voldemort will have the whole wizarding population under his eye from
>   a young age. And it’s also another way of weeding out Muggle-borns,
>   because students must be given Blood Status – meaning that they have
>   proven to the Ministry that they are of wizard descent – before they
>   are allowed to attend.’

The implication is that the decree **specifically states** that young British witches and wizards can no longer go overseas to be educated or be home-schooled. Obviously this quite closely parallels the German government's *Reichsschulpflichtgesetz* (federal compulsory attendance law), passed in 1938 as one of the actions of an ascendant Hitler administration.

Comment: I'm so glad I saw this before I'd really started typing that up myself! :P +1

Comment: Regarding the historical comparison, note that Hitler came to power in 1933, so a 1938 law can’t be counted among his _first_ actions. Furthermore, compulsory school attendance was already established by the 1919 Weimar Constitution; so it was only the restriction to domestic schools that was new.

Comment: @chirlu: The first laws regarding compulsory education in what later became Germany date back to the 16th century, actually.

Comment: @DevSolar: Yes, there were wildly different rules in the gazillion of German territories; but while there first were uniform rules for all of Germany (during the German Empire, from 1871 until the Weimar Constitution of 1919), home schooling was allowed.

Comment: @chirlu: You can't have uniform rules for Germany before Germany as such actually existed, i.e. 1871 onwards. ;-) But I see where you are coming from.

Comment: I find it interesting that Voldemort apparently wanted all witches & wizards to attend Hogwarts so he could keep an eye on them, but by refusing access to Muggle-borns he's allowing them to be sent abroad, out of his immediate reach.

Comment: @Jason - His long term plan appears to be to exterminate them. Having access to the magic quill at Hogwarts gives him the names and locations of every child in Britain with magical heritage.

Answer (score 0):

## Those who left early enough may have.

Once attending Hogwarts became compulsory, it would not be possible to legally choose to attend another wizarding school. However, there was about a year between Dumbledore’s death and attending Hogwarts becoming mandatory in which students *could* legally choose to no longer attend Hogwarts. After Dumbledore’s death, some students left Hogwarts before the funeral was held.

> “All lessons were suspended, all examinations postponed. Some students were hurried away from Hogwarts by their parents house over the next couple of days – the Patil twins were gone before breakfast on the morning following Dumbledore’s death and Zacharias Smith was escorted from the castle by his haughty-looking father. Seamus Finnigan, on the other hand, refused point-blank to accompany his mother home; they had a shouting match in the Entrance Hall which was resolved when she agreed that he could remain behind for the funeral.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 30 (The White Tomb)*</sup></sub>

Attendance at Hogwarts only became compulsory after July 31st the year after Dumbledore’s death, as Harry turned seventeen shortly before it was announced.

> “What’s Voldemort planning for Hogwarts?’ she asked Lupin.
>
> ‘Attendance is now compulsory for every young witch and wizard,’ he replied. ‘That was announced yesterday. It’s a change, because it was never obligatory before. Of course, nearly every witch and wizard in Britain has been educated at Hogwarts, but their parents had the right to teach them at home or send them abroad if they preferred. This way, Voldemort will have the whole wizarding population under his eye from a young age. And it’s also another way of weeding out Muggle-borns, because students must be given Blood Status – meaning that they have proven to the Ministry that they are of wizard descent – before they are allowed to attend.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 11 (The Bribe)*</sup></sub>

Students had about a year’s time to make the choice to leave Britain and attend another wizarding school. Some very well may have used this time to leave, enroll in a foreign school, and spend the time where Voldemort controlled Hogwarts safely away.